# How do I setup Event Tracking on my link and in Google Analytics so users clicking our login button to our app don't count as a bounce?

Tags: analytics-events

I have a website (`wwww.example.com`) and users will come to my site to click the login button on my app (`app.example.com`). This is currently counting as a bounce and I do not want it to since they are staying within our service. How do I do this?

Comment: See t[his](https://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2016/08/11/subdomain-tracking-google-analytics/) on how to setup tracking for subdomains.

Answer (score 3):

You need to enable **subdomain tracking**. You can do it in Google Analytics or [configure this through Google Tag Manager](https://www.clickinsight.ca/blog/cross-domain-subdomain-tracking-gtm). Those are the steps in Analytics:

### Setting the cookie

Set [cookieDomain](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference?hl=en#cookieDomain) to **auto** in order to create a cookie for the hole domain. It's the default value.

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', 'auto');
```

### Exclude your domain as referrer

Include your domain in the referral exclusion list (Admin Panel > Property > Tracking info > Referral Exclusion List).

[image]

Comment: I currently have Google Analytics set up for both my site and subdomain separately. Will this affect the separate tracking?

Comment: Of course. You need to have the same account for both site and subdomain, if not, you can't track users/sessions among them.